# What is the magnetic property of an alloy?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, matter

If an alloy is made between a diamagnetic and a paramagnetic substance or paramagnetic and a ferromagnetic substance or a diamagnetic and a ferromagnetic substance, what will be the resulting magnetic property of the alloy made between the respective materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a substances magnetic properties are tied to the spin pairing or lack of pairing for electrons in the outer orbitals it would vary on a case by case basis depending on what bonds occurred when alloying the substances.